# Vscode fatal error when running debug console

Tags: javascript, node.js

I keep getting this error [image]whenever I try to console log any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It was an error in my code in a for loop iteration :(.
Apparently the for loop had no break point.
I fixed it and the console worked with no issues.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need some form of an extension like   [Javascript debugger](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.js-debug-nightly)(It's available on the vscode extension store ). You do need to check if it does the job for you or not. Sharing your main code here might also help in better understanding the problem.

If you are using node.js , this is a good fix for your problem
[Fatal JavaScript invalid size error 169220804](https://github.com/Carnaux/NFT-Marker-Creator/issues/80)

Otherwise, reinstalling vscode from scratch might be another good option for you if everything else fails.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The problem was in my code and I fixed it.

Comment: An upvote is appreciated :)